# plotting dataframe boxplot side by side

Tags: python, dataframe, boxplot, valueerror

I am a new python user. I attached the screenshot of the data frame (df) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q3O6.png) which I got by combining (df1 = uncontrolled) and (df2 = controlled).

I want to plot the boxplot like this in descending format[as shown in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz9Gk.png)

My code is

```
df = df1.append(df2) 
sns.boxplot(df)
```

I am not getting the right graph

and

```
meds = df2.median()
meds.sort_values(ascending=False,inplace=True)
df2= df2[meds.index]
meds1 = df1.median()
meds2.sort_values(ascending=False,inplace=True)
df1= df1[meds.index] sns.boxplot(data=[df1,df2])
```

For above, I am getting - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'uncontrolled'

pls help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are looking for, first convert each dataframe from wide-form to long-form using [pandas melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Then, add a new column (I have used `Group`) and indicate that the df is `Controlled` or `Uncontrolled` - just for labelling. Post that, you can plot the data using boxplot with the `Group` as the x-data, the `values` as the y-data and the `variable` as hue. Working example shown below. Hope this helps...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

## First, melt the dataframes, so that it is changed from wide form to long 
df1=pd.melt(df1)
df2=pd.melt(df2)

## Add a new column so you know which is from df1 and which is from df2
df1['Group']='Controlled'
df2['Group']='Uncontrolled'

## Append the two dataframes
df = df1.append(df2)

## Plot - Note that you are setting the Group as x-axis and using the variable (A,B,...) or (0,1,..) in your case as hue
sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="value", hue='variable', data=df)
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
plt.gca().set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None)
```

[image]

**EDIT for sorting boxes**

Updated to including sorting - As you mentioned, just one (Uncontrolled) df will be sorted in descending order, you need to first get the index_sort of the values sorted by descending mean values. Also, df2 (Uncontrolled) needs to be first in the `append()`, so that these values are in the beginning.

Note that the lines in the middle of the boxes are for median. I have added `showmeans=True` so that you can see that the boxes are sorted by `Uncontrolled` in descending order. Updated code is below...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

## Get the means and sort in descending order to get index_sort
index_sort = df2.mean().sort_values(ascending=False).index
df2 = df2[index_sort]

## First, melt the dataframes, so that it is changed from wide form to long 
df1=pd.melt(df1)
df2=pd.melt(df2)


## Add a new column so you know which is from df1 and which is from df2
df1['Group']='Controlled'
df2['Group']='Uncontrolled'

## Append the two dataframes
df = df2.append(df1) ## Note we are now appending df1 to df2

## Plot - Note that you are setting the Group as x-axis and using the variable (A,B,...) or (0,1,..) in your case as hue
sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="value", hue='variable', data=df, showmeans=True) ## Additional showmeans for clarity
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
plt.gca().set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but can it be organize from "highest to lowest medium"?

Comment: There is no highest, medium or lowest in your data nor mine. What are you referring to?

Comment: I mean in your graph left side, the green one is the highest mean, so it should be like "green, blue, purple, red, yellow". something like that order

Comment: Should it be sorted descending by `Uncontrolled`? Asking because sorting by that may not sort it by the other column - controlled... is that ok?

Comment: yes, Uncontrolled is okay.

Comment: Updated code... refer to EDIT section for new plot

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I use your updated code but I am getting result like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSNWl.png). I don't know why. The result is not in the descending order for me.